# TensorFlow: restore graph with metrics op (e.g. accuracy), got error 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer'

Tags: graph, tensorflow, deep-learning, restore, tensor

After training a graph with metrics ops (such as accuracy from tf.python.ops.metrics), I tried to restore the graph and evaluate the accuracy on the test set. However, after restoring the graph with tf.import_meta_graph, when I tried to initialize the local variables (it is necessary) with tf.local_variables_initializer(), I got an error, it said 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer'.

If I print the local variables after restoring, there are two Tensorflow Tensors which may cause the problem.
These two tensorlow Tensors stem from the accuracy metrics:

```
  <tf.Tensor 'accuracy/total:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
  <tf.Tensor 'accuracy/count:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Similar code:

```
def train():
  l_ini = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=np.float32)
  p_ini = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], dtype=np.float32)
  l = tf.Variable(l_ini, trainable=False)
  p = tf.Variable(p_ini, trainable=False)
  accuracy = metrics.accuracy(labels=l, predictions=p)
  tf.add_to_collection("accuracy", accuracy)

  graph = tf.get_default_graph()

  sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  acc = sess.run(accuracy)

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  saver.save(sess, 'test.ckpt')

def restore():
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./test.ckpt.meta')
      loader.restore(sess, './test.ckpt')
      accuracy = tf.get_collection("accuracy")

      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
      acc = sess.run(accuracy)
```

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it or are you able to offer any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround, instead of retrieving the accuracy collection (the `get_collection` returned an empty list in my case):

- Retrieve the logits and label placeholders.
- Then compute the accuracy.
- Remember to initialize the local running variables after restoring to session as well: 
  `self.running_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES, scope="your_accuracy_scope_name")`